# Swift: How to make a method to be called every 10 seconds

Tags: ios, swift

In my main ViewController ViewDidLoad, I have the following code that calls the "tick" method every second.

```
self.timerTick = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In the "tick" method, I check if a boolean value is true every second, and if true, I need to call a second method called SpeakText(), but I want to call the SpeakText() only once every 10 seconds. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class property to keep track of the time since the last `SpeakText`.  Update it each time `tick` is called, and reset it to `0` when `SpeakText` is called:

```
var secondsSinceSpeakText = 10

func tick() {
    secondsSinceSpeakText += 1
    if boolFlag && secondsSinceSpeakText >= 10 {
        SpeakText()
        secondsSinceSpeakText = 0
    }
}
```

Note:  Starting `secondsSinceSpeakText` with an initial value of `10` will allow the first `SpeakText` to happen immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another timer for speaktext when and when you call your speak text function fire it. If its under 10 seconds return false